# SQL Database Tools in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to setup my Visual Studio Project to be able to use only one IDE for managing SQL objects using TFS 2012. Is there any way to configure my project connected to a source control and if for example I go to SSMS and try to modify a stored procedure, automatically takes the one in the source control or vice versa using Visual Studio 2012 check out a procedure and from SSMS shows me that is checked out?

No matter where I'm (Management Studio or Visual Studio 2012)the SQL objects are synchronized.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't provide any built-in support but you can link your SSDT database project to SSMS using the latest version of SQL Source Control, which is a commercial tool developed by Red Gate, the company I work for. Steps are:

- Download [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) and install it (it has a 28-day free trial)
- Load SSMS, right click on your database in the object explorer and select the Link to Source Control option.
- In the Link dialog, browse to the database project folder in your repository.

That's it. It's now set up. Simply use the Commit and Get Latest tabs to keep your database in sync with your database project in source control.

I'd be happy to assist should you hit any problems. Please add a comment to this answer or contact support@red-gate.com